# Is there a dictionary api or something similar where I can find the definition of words in PHP?

Tags: php, dictionary

Does anybody know of any? (I'd be using a php page to call the terms)

THANKS!

Comment: a dictionary api as in [getDefinition("str_replace")]?  With the offline manual and some fancy grepping you could rig one up...

Answer (score 0):

developer.dictionary.com has an api. decent. They have a public/enterprise version based on your needs.

Comment: www.mydictionaryapi.com is an example of their API.

Answer (score -1):

There is not a built in dictionary API in PHP, but a quick search showed a few code samples and other resources you can use to build your own.

Comment: for what it's worth, whenever you tell someone there's resources out there, but give no links to even one of them - it's the same as saying "dunno, but I'm sure someone does."